# How can I detect if a windows mobile device has the keyboard extended?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, hardware, pocketpc, soft-keyboard

How can I detect if a windows mobile device has the keyboard extended? I am manually launching the soft keyboard and I need to know when to prevent my app from launching the PIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [SHSipInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932724.aspx) ?

Alternatively, if your application is maximized, you can try to get the Client/Window size of your window, close the keyboard using [SHSipPreference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931564.aspx) and get the size of the window again. if the size become longer then probably the sip was open. keep these window sizes for later comparisons.